# How do I save a child entity in EntityFramework 4?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a 1-1 relationship between Orders and Contact. i.e. Contact.OrderId references Orders and is also a PK.

So I have an existing Order and I add a new Contact to it like so...

```
    order.Contact = new Contact() { EmailAddress = "hello" };
    context.Orders.Attach(order);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh I've got it! The order needs to be attached to the context _before_ the contact is assigned to it. Otherwise the context doesn't know that the contact has been added! Then one doesn't even need to set the OrderId field on the contact. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generate your child entity, set its `OrderIdReference` property and you should be good to go.

Comment: Seems to work. But I'm confused by the behaviour that I've mentioned in a comment on the original question.

Comment: @Ian Warburton: This technique I proposed is the fastest and you can bypass certain database calls. But what you did was that you've done some changes before attaching your entity to concrete DB record. You always have to attach it first then do anything you have to and then comit all those changes you've made.

Comment: Hey Robert, I take it back. I made a mistake. When I set the OrderId on Contact object the Contact object doesn't get saved. Do I need to tell the context that the Contact is new?

Comment: Create a new `Contact`, set its properties (including `OrderIdReference`), add it to contacts table and save. That should be it, as long as your order doesn't have an existing contact (since you say you have a 1-1 reference).

Comment: Nope.. its not working for me. Does the Contact entity need to be added like this, 'context.Add(contactEntity);' because I've got it in mind that I can add it to an existing order, 'Attach' the order to the context and EF will find the new contact in the order.

Comment: 'context.Contacts.Add(contactEntity);'

Comment: @Ian: I can't say exactly what the problem is but you can always take the slow road: load the order from DB, add contact and save changes. That always works. But I suggest you check other means as well because that requires two roundtrips to DB.

Comment: Ahh... perhaps it makes a difference loading the Order with one context and saving it with another...

Answer (score 1):

You have a 1-to-1 relationship with shared primary key in `Order` and `Contact` table: The PK of a contact must always be the same as the PK of the associated order. This has some consequences:

- Only one of the PK columns in `Order` and `Contact` table can be an autogenerated identity. I assume it is the `Order` table.
- If `order` already had a `Contact` before you assign the new one, you must delete the old contact explicitely from the database because you cannot have two contacts with the same OrderId since it is the PK at the same time.
- Because `Contact` table doesn't have an identity column you must supply the PK manually in code and it must be the PK of the order.

To put this together, it might look like:

```
context.Orders.Attach(order);
if (order.Contact != null)
    context.DeleteObject(order.Contact);
order.Contact = new Contact() { OrderId = order.Id, EmailAddress = "hello" };
context.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes that 1) the old `order.Contact` is loaded into the order object if there was already a Contact before you assign a new one and 2) that the property `OrderId` of `Contact` is the PK property.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but i think you need to set the pk for your contact object. Entity framework doesnt like it when you dont have Primary keys null.

Answer (score 0):

The new contract has not been added:

```
context.Orders.Attach(order);
context.AddToContractSet(order.Contract);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This is assuming that `order` is already in the DB, and you are attaching because it originally came from another context.  If not, just do this:

```
context.AddToORdersSet(order);
context.SaveChanges();
```