# EF 5, update object gives "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In my model I've got a bunch of domain objects. Now I'm having a problem when trying to update a User-object. The User has a foreignkey relation to the Role object. When I update the User-object without changeing the foreignkey value (FkRoleId) it all works fine. But when I change the role for the current user I want to update I get the error:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

Here's how I update my user-object:

```
public void Update(User user)
{
    using (var context = new DBEntities())
    { 
    context.Entry(user).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

How can I update my user-object without getting this exception? 
There must be a way for chaning the foreignkey value for mappen the user to another role.

Here's my domain classes in this case:

```
public partial class User
{
public User()
{
    this.Advertisers = new HashSet<Advertiser>();
    this.Cases = new HashSet<Case>();
    this.Materials = new HashSet<Material>();
}

public int PkId { get; set; }
public int FkRoleId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Advertiser> Advertisers { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Case> Cases { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}


public partial class Role
{
public Role()
{
    this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
}

public int PkId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: However; if I set the navigation property user.Role to null it works just fine. But, is this the recommended way of working??

Comment: This may be a duplicate of these QA's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679703/how-do-i-save-a-child-entity-in-entityframework-4, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716733/updating-foreign-key-associations-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856588/how-to-update-complex-model-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To quote your comment:

> However; if I set the navigation property user.Role to null it works
>   just fine. But, is this the recommended way of working?

Yes, in this case it is.

You must keep in mind that you enter a new context with a detached object `user` (including the reference to `user.Role`). By setting the state to `Modified` you attach the object `user` together with the related `user.Role` to this new context.

Because your are using a foreign key association - that means that the foreign key is represented by a property `FkRoleId` in the model class - the relationship is described in two ways: By the navigation property `user.Role` and by the scalar property `user.FkRoleId`. If these are not consistent - i.e. `user.Role.PkId != user.FkRoleId` - EF doesn't know which one describes the correct relationship and throws the exception you have.

If you set `user.Role` to `null` EF will consider the `user.FkRoleId` alone as the property that describes the relationship between user and role and the ambiguity that was causing the exception is removed.

Comment: And what if I need to attach an object with changed navigation property and intact scalar one? Can I somehow tell EF to use navigation property as "primary"?

Comment: @Vasaka: No, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of searchers, I was getting the same error but found a quick fix.

I was loading a class with an FK relationship into the view to be edited. Even with no changes, the FK was being dropped and this error occurred. The fix was to include a hidden field into the Razor view that contained the FK. e.g.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReleaseInfo.BookId)
```

Code copied below so you can check if your situation is similar.

Controller Actions

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            Book book = db.Books.Find(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.ReleaseInfo, "BookId", "BookId", book.Id);
            return View(book);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Book/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Book book)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.ReleaseInfo, "BookId", "BookId", book.Id);
            return View(book);
        }
```

Relationships

Book.cs

```
  public class Book
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Title { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }


        public virtual ReleaseInfo ReleaseInfo { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<ReRelease> ReReleases { get; set; }

    }
```

ReleaseInfo.cs

```
public class ReleaseInfo
    {
        // One to one relationship uses Books Key as Key.
        [Key, ForeignKey("Book")]
        public int BookId { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }


        public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    }
```