# Saving related models with entityframework - A referential integrity constraint violation occurred

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following models

Factory can have multiple Cars, A Car can have TypeA & TypeB

```
public class Factory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FactoryID {get;set;}

    public ICollection<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarID {get;set;}

    public int FactoryID {get;set;}
    public Factory Factory {get;set;}

    //The Types
    public TypeA TypeA {get;set;}
    public TypeB TypeB {get;set;}
}

public class TypeA
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeAID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}

public class TypeB
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeBID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}
```

Which is shown in an EditorTemplate with the following

```
Factory factory = Factory factory = db.Factory.Where(f => f.FactoryID == 1)
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeA))
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeB)).FirstOrDefault();
```

I just post the model to view and so on and so forth. Then comes the time to post the data back to the model.

I have the following action, which is my post action.

```
public ActionResult FactoryEdit(Factory factory)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.entry(factory).State = EntityState.Modified;//<- Error here!
        db.SaveChanges(); 
        //Redirect
    }
    //Return view
}
```

When I try to get the Factory thats been changed I get the following error

**A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.**

I'm trying to update the entire Factory object including the list of cars and TypeA & TypeB

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF 5, update object gives "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376376/ef-5-update-object-gives-a-referential-integrity-constraint-violation-occurred)

Comment: Definitely not - Same error message though, I looked at that one, before i posted my question